# Extracting max date from a database and use output in another query

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to query max date in a table and use this as parameter in a where clausere in another query.  I am doing this:

```
  query = (""" select 
        cast(max(order_date) as date)
    from 
        tablename
     """)
    cursor.execute(query)
    d = cursor.fethcone()
```

as output:`[(datetime.date(2021, 9, 8),)]`

Then I want to use this output as parameter in another query:

```
query3=("""select * from anothertable

     where order_date = d::date limit 10""")

cursor.execute(query3)
```

as output: `column "d" does not exist`

I tried to `cast(d as date)` , `d::date` but nothing works. I also tried to `datetime.date(d)` no success too.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Strings don't automatically interpret variables. Do you understand how to give query parameters? It's mentioned very clearly in the documentation for the sql client you're using, I bet. Besides, you probably should format your Python datetime object so that it matches the database date format. Otherwise, you could just use a nested subquery so that you don't need two execute statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to select the date then use it in another query. That requires 2 round trips to the server. Do it in a single query. This has the advantage of removing all client side processing of that date.

```
select * 
  from anothertable 
 where order_date = 
       ( select max(cast(order_date as date ))
           from tablename
       );
```

I am not exactly how this translates into your obfuscation layer but, from what I see, I believe it would be something like.

```
query = (""" select * 
               from anothertable 
              where order_date = 
                    ( select max(cast(order_date as date ))
                       from tablename
                    ) """)

cursor.execute(query)
```

Heed the warning by @OneCricketeer. You may need cast on anothertable order_date as well. So `where cast(order_date as date) = ( select ... )`